# Typescript cast to void for Observable

Tags: typescript

I have a class like so:

```
class Consumer {
  consume(event: Observable<void>) {
    event.subscribe(() => console.log('Something happened'));
  }
}
```

My source observable is not void:

```
const obs = Observable.interval(1000);
```

The two clumsy solutions I could come up with for consuming the observable are:

```
// Bad (wasteful call to map)
consumer.consume(obs.map(() => {}));
// Bad (confusing syntax)
consumer.consume(obs as any as Observable<void>);
```

What is the best way to cast my observable to `Observable<void>` so I can consume it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic type on the function covers this case well:

```
class Consumer {
  consume<X>(event: Observable<X>) {
    event.subscribe(() => console.log('Something happened'));
  }
}
```

Note that the direct "fix" of using `Observable<any>` sacrifices type safety. For instance, it allows the implementation

```
consume(event: Observable<any>) {
  event.subscribe((value) => value.literallyAnyMethod());
}
```

...without any compiler errors. This situation (and many like it) have prompted many codebases to implement rules disallowing `any`.

I don't believe TypeScript has single, non-generic type which allows your safe implementation but not my unsafe implementation, so the generic type X, though unused, is the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is not `Observable<void>`, but `Observable<any>`. That will allow you to pass any observable into `consume()`. If you really must cast, then `as any as Observable<void>` is probably your best bet.